# react-minimal-pie-chart label color is not changing

Tags: reactjs, pie-chart

I recently discovered `react-minimal-pie-chart` and I think it is pretty dope and flexible (at least it solves my use case). However, it seems I can't change the label font color. This is strange because I can change literally anything but the font color. Anyone has any idea why? It wouldn't be much of a problem but it interferes with the design I'm trying to respect.

[Here is the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9THT1.png) and [here is the result so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlR7m.png).

`"react-minimal-pie-chart": "^8.2.0"` this is the version I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the fill property from css,

```
<PieChart
    labelStyle={{
                  fill: 'white',
                  fontSize: '10px'
             }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks man! I didn't try this, but it works. Only if you answered this earlier by 1 week so I can update it for my thesis :)) Anyway thanks a lot!